# Git only allow merge from development into master

Tags: git, merge, branch

I'd like be able to setup our branches so that merges can only go into master from the development branch.

I understand that perhaps this sounds draconian and I should to ask myself the question, do i not trust the developers on the team... For the time being I don't because they're just becoming familiar with Git. In time I'll remove the restriction but until then this would be a useful. Is it possible?

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: Couldn't you just revert their changes if they do mess up?

Comment: yes I could and thanks for the reply but that doesn't address the question

Comment: You don't want to revert a messy master every other week if you can just set up a hook and be done with it. Saves time and nerves.

Comment: Some git hosting servers allow you to disallow push to certain branches, and would have to file a pull request. Bitbucket does this at least. Perhaps this would be a simple option? Look for something similar to "Branch permissions".

Comment: Started a discussion here: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/56942

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [kowsky answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43369081/1256452), it's possible to do this in a server-side pre-receive hook.  It is surprisingly difficult though, primarily because Git's notion of a branch is somewhat slippery.

I wrote a pre-receive hook that does this, among other things; [the code is available here](http://web.torek.net/torek/git/pre-receive.sh.txt).  See the `merges_from` function, and note the comments above it.  Since links are a bit iffy in StackOverflow I will include the actual function here as well.  (Note that this code is meant to work with positively ancient versions of Git, so it does not use modern features like `git for-each-ref --merged`.)

---

```
# $1 is a merge commit.  Find all its parents, except the first
# (which is "on" the branch being merged-into and hence not relevant).
# For each remaining parent, find which branch(es) contain them.
# If those branch heads *are* them, consider that the "source" of the merge.
#
# Note that this means if branches A and B both name commit 1234567,
# and you merge commit 1234567 into branch master, this considers
# the merge (with its one parent) to merge both branches A and B.
# That may not be ideal, but it is what we get...
merges_from()
{
    local branches b src

    set -- $($GIT rev-list --parents --no-walk $1)
    shift 2
    for i do
        # git branch --contains may print something like
        #    * (no branch)
        # or
        #    * (detached from blah)
        # if HEAD is detached.  This should not happen in
        # a bare repo, but if it does, we'll add HEAD to
        # our list.
        branches=$($GIT branch --merged $i |
            sed -e 's/\* (.*)/HEAD/' -e 's/^[* ]//')
        set -- $branches
        src=""
        for b do
            if [ $($GIT rev-parse $b) = $i ]; then
                src="${src}${src:+ }$b"
            fi
            [ "$src" == "" ] && src="-"
        done
        echo $src
    done
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million Torek, I will give this a shot the first opportunity that I get. Unfortunately I only get a few hours a week on this particular project. I'll respond back with how successful I got on.

Comment: @MarkGargan Any news?

Answer (score 0):

It's not draconian at all, it makes perfect sense and prevents severe accidents.

Having that said: you can control things like this via [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). These are scripts that are executed on certain events. In your case, a server side pre-receive or a client side pre-push hook like [this](https://dev.ghost.org/prevent-master-push/) or [this](https://gist.github.com/pixelhandler/5718585) will help.