# BitBucket Server Git - Only allow merge from branch UAT into master

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

Right now we are working with a total of four environments and we have one branch per environment: develop, QA, UAT and master (production). We also have an extra branch based on our current release number that we work against. Every Jira task/story/bug etc have their own feature branch/hotfix branch that is then merged into the current release number branch.

Our current work flow is based on Gitflow but instead of creating new branches from develop we are using the release number branch. We could of course do the full Gitflow workflow and only create a release branch when we are ready to release and only allow bug fixes, documentation generation, and other release-oriented tasks to go in this branch but this is not the point of the question. We require a pull request for each branch using branch permission "Prevent changes without a pull request".

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver045/using-bitbucket-server/controlling-access-to-code/using-branch-permissions

This is proving quite cumbersome since new code will have to go through five pull requests to reach master. Even if it is fast to approve since all code should already be approved in the later stages it is a major overhead. To get something into development is two pull requests, one from release branch `1.2.3` and one to develop for example.

What we would like to do is require a pull request to our release branch (`1.2.3`) and that only the release branch is allowed to be merged into development, without requiring a pull request. It should then only be possible to merge develop into QA etc.

I read about a server-side pre-receive hook here but I'm unsure how this could be implemented on Bitbucket Server. Has anyone done anything like this?

[Git only allow merge from development into master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368651/git-only-allow-merge-from-development-into-master)

The same question on Bitbucket forum:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Only-allow-merge-from-branch-UAT-into-master/qaq-p/1062136#U1062160

Comment: If you vote down please add a comment why. Very hard to improve question quality otherwise.

Comment: You could implement the method described in your link 'Git only allow merge from development into master'. This requires administrator access to the Bitbucket server, in order to manually update the repository. This is a workable solution provided you don't have too many repositories to maintain. The alternative is probably writing your own pre-recieve hook which you then enable under Merge Checks. See https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/hooks-merge-checks-guide/